# Don't display empty select results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a T-SQL script that performs many select statements. Most times these statements don't return anything, so the output shows something like this:

[script results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejKrQ.png).

Is there a way to not show the headers of the select if the result is empty?

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: Insert the results into a temp table or table variable, and then select the final results.

Comment: Or use a `IF` statement and check if any records are going to be returned before carrying out the `SELECT`.

Comment: Since the result sets appear to be compatible, i.e. all of the columns are `pixel` data, you could `union all` the `select`s into a single result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select into a #temp table and only select from it if you inserted any rows.

```
SELECT <cols> INTO #a
  FROM dbo.somewhere
  WHERE …;

If @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
  SELECT <cols> FROM #a;
END

SELECT <cols> INTO #b
  FROM dbo.somewhere_else
  WHERE …;

If @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
  SELECT <cols> FROM #b;
END

…
```

Or if all the resultsets are identical, you could do:

```
DECLARE @rc int = 0;

SELECT <cols> INTO #a
  FROM dbo.somewhere
  WHERE …;

SET @rc += @@ROWCOUNT;

SELECT <cols> INTO #b
  FROM dbo.somewhere_else
  WHERE …;

SET @rc += @@ROWCOUNT;

...

IF @rc > 0
BEGIN
  SELECT <cols> FROM #a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT <cols> FROM #b
  UNION ALL
  ...;
END
```

Or even:

```
SELECT <cols> INTO #x FROM 
(
  SELECT <cols> FROM dbo.somewhere
  UNION ALL
  SELECT <cols> FROM dbo.somewhere_else
  UNION ALL
  ...
) AS x;

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
  SELECT <cols> FROM #x;
END
```

And if you need to know which table a row came from:

```
SELECT <cols> INTO #x FROM 
(
  SELECT src = 'somewhere', <cols> FROM dbo.somewhere
  UNION ALL
  SELECT src = 'somewhere_else', <cols> FROM dbo.somewhere_else
  ...
) AS x;

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
  SELECT src, <cols> FROM #x;
END
```